# Granting access to signed applet not working

Tags: java, windows, security, security-roles, signed-applet

I have created signed applet to read file from client side. Now I have been facing problem 
with different roles of Operating System users.

**E.G.**
I tried a sample signed applet from the Sun site - it worked fine while I was logged on as
administrator, but failed while logged on as a regular user.

I am using following environment:

- Operating System: Windows 7
- Browser: IE 8

I feel that it is definitely problem of operating system different roles. But I have to deploy the signed applet functionality in non administrator role.

How can I do this without administrator role?

Comment: Your problem could be caused by many things, but without some sort of error message/exception/log entry, there's no way to know. Please provide more info so we can give you more help.

Comment: Which sample applet did you use?

Answer (score 1):

> I have created signed applet to read file from client side..

It is not necessary to sign an applet to gain access to the client file system if the applet is deployed using JWS in a 1.6.0_10+ (Next Generation Plug-In) JRE.  Such applets have access to the JNLP API FileContents object.  Here is a [demo. of the FileContents object](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

> ..Please help how can i do without administrator role.

But ultimately, if the file access is barred (for the specific file in question) by the OS, there is nothing that Java can (or should) do about it.

Perhaps the real problem is the exact *path* of this file.  What is it?  What does it do?  Where is it located and can that path be changed?  A sub-directory of user.home is a good place to store anything of interest to the application that is subject to change.

For storing small amounts of data, JWS also offers the [PersistenceService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps) to all apps., including sand-boxed.